# Overfull hbox + regression table

Tags: tables, overfull

When I export my regression table from R (stargazer package) to overleaf, I get the following error message: Overfull hbox  (38.93 too wide) in paragraph at lines xxx.

I could not find a way to adjust the table?
I tried the adjust box package but the issue persists.

```
\begin{table}
\begingroup
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
      \tabularnewline \midrule \midrule
      \emph{Dependent variable}: & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Battles} \\
       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Growing season} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Non-growing season} \\ 
       \midrule 
                         & (1)      & (2)\\  
      \midrule 
      VCIshock                                         & 0.006             &   \\   
                                                       & (0.005)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Tropics,highland`             & 0.028$^{***}$     &   \\   
                                                       & (0.009)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Tropics,lowland`              & -0.024$^{**}$     &   \\   
                                                       & (0.010)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Subtropics,moderatelycool`    & -0.014            &   \\   
                                                       & (0.009)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Subtropics,cool`              & 0.025             &   \\   
                                                       & (0.018)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Cold,nopermafrost`            & 0.016             &   \\   
                                                       & (0.016)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Extremesoilconditions`        & 0.005             &   \\   
                                                       & (0.009)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Dominantlybuiltupland`        & -0.120            &   \\   
                                                       & (0.078)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Dominantlyhydromorphicsoils`  & -0.019            &   \\   
                                                       & (0.012)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Dominantlywater`              & -0.023            &   \\   
                                                       & (0.021)           &   \\   
      VCIshock $\times$ `Desert,AridClimate`           & 0.020$^{*}$       &   \\   
                                                       & (0.011)           &   \\   
      TCIshock                                         &                   & 0.017$^{*}$\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.009)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Tropics,highland`             &                   & -0.021$^{*}$\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.013)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Tropics,lowland`              &                   & -0.019\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.018)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Subtropics,moderatelycool`    &                   & 0.001\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.007)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Subtropics,cool`              &                   & 0.013\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.016)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Cold,nopermafrost`            &                   & -0.007\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.008)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Extremesoilconditions`        &                   & 0.004\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.016)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Dominantlybuiltupland`        &                   & 0.044\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.072)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Dominantlyhydromorphicsoils`  &                   & 0.015\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.013)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Dominantlywater`              &                   & -0.001\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.017)\\   
      TCIshock $\times$ `Desert,AridClimate`           &                   & 0.021\\   
                                                       &                   & (0.018)\\   
       \\
      Observations                                     & 70,171            & 59,725\\  
      R$^2$                                            & 0.28538           & 0.26516\\  
    \item {\emph{Fixed-effects}}:\\
      gid FE  & X        & X             & X        & X\\  
      Year FE & X        & X             & X        & X\\  
      \bottomrule

   \multicolumn{4}{l}{\emph{Signif. Codes: ***: 0.01, **: 0.05, *: 0.1}}
\end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
   \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
    \small
    \item {\emph{Notes}}: Standard errors clustered at the cell level are in parentheses. The dependant variable 'Violence' is the occurrence of conflict coded 
         as one if a conflict happened in a given cell/year; 
         '*shock':  fraction of the corresponding season during which the index is below the threshold representing drought conditions i.e., $<$-1.5 for SPEI, $<$40 for VCI and TCI;
        Variables columns (1) to (2): Growing season and columns (3) to (4): Non-growing season. 
 
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\par\endgroup
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Overfull is a warning not an error message. If you want real help you should consider posting a Minimal Working Example. Quick and dirty you can add a `\tiny` or `\footnotesize` command after the `\centering` command.

Comment: Off topic. Wiiting `70171` as `70,171` is not legal in the `SI` writing `70\,171` is legal.

Comment: What do you mean by a minimal working example ? As for the \tiny suggestion, it does not give a good result.

Comment: have a look at (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)